# mostrar datos pdo php select

Tags: php, pdo, select

Estoy terminando un sistema web pero tengo un problema en el `select` en vez de cargarme las tres opciones que son administrador , estudiante , docente , me carga mas de una sola vez.

Aquí está el código model

```
public function getObtenerDatosUsuario()
    {
        $rows=null;
        $statement=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $statement->execute();
        while($result=$statement->fetch())
        {
            $rows[]=$result;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
```

Visualización en html, código php select

```
 <?php
                          $Usuarios = $ModeloUsuarios->getUsers();
                          if($Usuarios!=null){
                            foreach($Usuarios as $Usuario){

                              ?>
                               <option value=""><?php echo $Usuario['perfil'];?></option>
                               
                               
                              <?php
                            }
                          }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

No me carga las 3 opciones, me carga las mismas opciones una y otra vez como se muestra en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla users

[image: esta es la tabla users]

Comment: qué tienes en tu tabla `users`? Me da la impresión que esa tabla tiene a todos tus usuarios. Lo recomendable es que tengas una tabla aparte con "roles" o "perfiles". Lo que podrías haces es modificar tu consulta, pero no se si esos datos los uses en otra parte. La consulta modificada sería algo como `select distinct perfil from users`

Comment: Estás llenando los ´option` según la totalidad de usuarios: `foreach($Usuarios as $Usuario){` Aparte de que podrías tener un lío en tus tablas, ¿no sería más fácil usar un array con los tres tipos de perfiles que existen  o consultar aparte la tabla de perfiles para obtener los `option`? Aunque el contexto no lo explicas con claridad, por ejemplo, ¿qué se debe poner en ese `select` por cada usuario?

Comment: deberias de crear una tabla perfil y hacer la relacion 1 perfil puede tener muchos usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Para tu caso lo que aplica es hacer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT perfil FROM user
```

y al momento de desplegar en el `<option>` este mismo campo tendrías que colocarlo como `value` y como descripción. Es decir, deberá ser:

```
<option value="<?php echo $Usuario['perfil'];?>"><?php echo $Usuario['perfil'];?></option>
```

> Cuidado que en tu código que proporcionas `value` no lo estas asignando; por tanto cuando quieras usar el valor siempre obtendrás cadena vacía sin importar cual eligan.

Te comento, el detalle que tienes parece ocurre por que (conforme a imagen que muestras) el campo `perfil` parece es ingresado no es de un catálogo; digamos si tuvieras tabla catálogo (sin entrar mucho a detalle):

Catálogo **Perfiles**

```
Perfiles (idPerfil [este seria un entero de autoincremento], Descripcion [ este seria texto])
```

y en tu tabla **users** en vez de campo `perfil` la renombras y la relacion con su correspondiente (en esta sugerencia) `idPerfil`; con consultar `SELECT * FROM Perfiles` no tendrías tantas repeticiones. Así, usarias:

```
/* Obtener todos los perfiles */
$perfiles = $ModeloPerfiles->getPerfiles(); /* Esto seria crearlo con SQL antes mencionado */

<option value="<?php echo $perfiles['idPerfil'];?>"><?php echo $perfiles['Descripcion'];?></option>
```